# Bash / ZSH - How to copy from a specific line to the end of a file, then paste at line 1 of another file whist preserving all text in that file

Tags: linux, bash, azure-devops

I am trying to add a bash script to my Azure Devops pipeline that automatically compiles a changelog.

When a PR is made, there will be a file committed call `pr-changelog.md`. I want all text from this file to be copied from a specific line onwards, say line 6. then I want this pasted in to another file called `changelog.md` at line 1, moving all text in that file down and preserving it. Both of these files will be at the root of my folder.

So far I have seen commands like `cp`, `sed` and `awk` suggested, but I am not sure how to target these specific files and paste in the last step to always preserve what's already there.

What should my bash script be using to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following :

```
cat <(tail -n+7 pr-changelog.md) changelog.md > output
mv output changelog.md
```

`tail` returns the end of the `pr-changelog.md` file, starting with line 7 when using `-n+7`.
`<(...)` is process substitution and will return the output stream of the command, which can be read by `cat`.
We concatenate that to the current `changelog.md` file to obtain the new one.

Careful not to try and do it in one operation : the `> changelog.md` would overwrite the content of `changelog.md` before it is read by `cat`.